# Error saving forms to two different tables

Tags: django, django-models

This is my form , when i save it , it saves only to the User model but not the Client model in the database , i must be missing something simple but i cant figure it out. The following is the Form and the Client model

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(label="Email")
    fullname = forms.CharField(label="Full name")
    type_choice= ( ('Customer','Customer'),('Supplier','Supplier'), )
    type=forms.ChoiceField(choices=type_choice)
    gender_choice=( ('Male','Male'), ('Female','Female'), )
    gender=forms.ChoiceField(choices=gender_choice)
    address=forms.CharField(label="Address",initial="Nothing")
    phone_number=forms.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model= User
        fields = ("username","fullname","email","type","gender","address","phone_number")

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegisterForm, self).save(commit=False)

        first_name, last_name = self.cleaned_data["fullname"].split()
        user.first_name = first_name
        user.last_name = last_name
        user.email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        user.type=self.cleaned_data["type"]

        user.gender=self.cleaned_data["gender"]
        user.address=self.cleaned_data["address"]
        user.phone_number=self.cleaned_data["phone_number"]
        client=    Client(Client_ID=3,Client_FirstName=first_name,Client_PhoneNumber=user.phone_number)

        if commit:
            user.save()
            client.save()
        return user,client
```

This is the Client model

```
 class Client(models.Model):
     Client_ID= models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)    
     Client_FirstName=models.CharField(max_length=30)
     Client_LastName=models.CharField(max_length=30)
     Client_Gender=models.CharField(max_length=30)
     Client_PhoneNumber=models.IntegerField()
     Client_Address=models.CharField(max_length=100)
     Client_CreditRating=models.FloatField()
```

edit : I am following this [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/) to insert a new entry into the table

Comment: This is updating Client instance with Client_ID 3 all the time (hard coded primary key). Is that what you want?

Comment: I want to insert a Client instance into the database. Why is the above a UPDATE ????

Comment: Well, look at `client = Client(Client_ID=3, [...]`. How does this not overwrite Client with pk=3 all the time? And your example link just links to a huge Django doc page. What exact example are you referring to?

Comment: How is the `Client` model related to `User` model?

Comment: The above link , Second Paragraph : Creating Objects

Comment: @user2284926 In that example a `Blog` model is instantiated without specifying the primary key. That's exactly my point in my previous comment.